# How can I modify my Abaqus python code to only extract nodeset coordinates?

Tags: python, abaqus, finite-element-analysis

Using several example scripts found online, I have managed to extract the coordinates of an Abaqus simulation from the .odb file. However, I would like to **only** extract the coordinates of a certain nodeset e.g. a nodeset called "NS-1". Information on specifically extracting nodeset coordinates using Python in Abaqus is sparse, and I have tried many supposed solutions that do not work.

Would anyone be able to advise me how my code needs to be modified in order to extract coordinates of a certain node set? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
import sketch
import visualization
import xyPlot
import displayGroupOdbToolset as dgo
import connectorBehavior
import shutil
import os
import sys
from odbAccess import openOdb
from odbAccess import openOdb

for ODBname in os.listdir("D:/AbaqusWorking/Coordtest"): 
    ODBnamefull = "D:/AbaqusWorking/Coordtest/Job-1.odb"
    odb = openOdb(path=ODBnamefull)  
    
    assembly = odb.rootAssembly    
    
    modelname = "Test"
    
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].odbDisplay.setFrame(step=0, frame=1)
    numNodes = 0   
    f = open("D:/AbaqusWorking/Coordtest/Testing.csv", "w") 
    for name, instance in assembly.instances.items(): 
        n = len(instance.nodes) 
        print 'Number of nodes of instance %s: %d' % (name, n) 
        numNodes = numNodes + n 
        f.write("Name,Node,X,Y,Z" + "\n")   

        if instance.embeddedSpace == THREE_D: 
            for node in instance.nodes:
                f.write(str(modelname) + "," )
                f.write(str(node.label) + "," ) 
                f.write(str(node.coordinates[0]) + "," + str(node.coordinates[1]) + "," + str(node.coordinates[2]) + "\n") 
        else: 
            for node in instance.nodes:
                f.write( str(node.label) + ";" )
                f.write(str(node.coordinates[0]) + "," + str(node.coordinates[1]) + "," + str(node.coordinates[2]) + "\n") 
        f.write( "*End Part" ) 
    print 'Write to file complete'
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Set Object](https://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/2009/spring/mase5513/abaqus/docs/v6.6/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch05pyo04.html) of the Abaqus Scripting Reference Manual. You can access a set through several ways, but looks like the one most useful to you would be inside of your loop over the instances using `instance.sets["NS-1"]`